# Properties of Lie subalgebra complements

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces

I have a Lie algebra that breaks up into as subalgebra $B$ and its complement $\overline B$ (dividing the set of Lie generators into mutually exclusive subsets $B$ and $\overline B$ such that $B$ is a subalgebra but $\overline B$ is not). Then I find the property:
$$
  \forall L_a \in B, \forall J_b \in \overline B:
$$
$$
  [L_a, L_b] \in B,
$$
$$
  [J_a, J_b] \in B,
$$
$$
  [L_a, J_b] \in \overline B
$$
Here is an example of one instance of this:

```
[[e1, e2] = -2*e3, [e1, e3] = 2*e2, [e1, e5] = -2*e6, [e1, e6] = 2*e5, [e2, e3] = -2*e1, [e2, e4] = 2*e6, [e2, e6] = -2*e4, [e3, e4] = -2*e5, [e3, e5] = 2*e4, [e4, e5] = 2*e3, [e4, e6] = -2*e2, [e5, e6] = 2*e1]
```

Does this property have a name? Or is it related to something else I can lookup somewhere? References appreciated.

Comment: Note: the subalgebra is neither normal nor an ideal.

Comment: According to maple, it has no Levi decomposition.

Comment: Every finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra has a Levi decomposition. This is a theorem.

Comment: Rather, the Levi Decomposition is the entire algebra, which doesn't tell me anything.

Answer (score 2):

This Lie algebra $L$ is a perfect $6$-dimensional Lie algebra, i.e., it satisfies $[L,L]=L$. So it must be isomorphic to one of the following Lie algebras:
$$
\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\ltimes V(3),\; \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\ltimes \mathfrak{n}_3(\Bbb C),\; \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\times \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C).
$$
Here $V(3)$ is the adjoint $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$-module, and $\mathfrak{n}_3(\Bbb C)$ is the Heisenberg Lie algebra. The Levi decomposition also yields a vector space decomposition into subalgebras (subspaces which are not subalgebras usually have no name).

Comment: It's pretty clearly related to $sl(2,C) \times sl(2,C)$. But I'm considering a real lie algebra.  I guess I'm looking for an isomorphism to one of the real representations of $sl(2,R)$ or $so(2,1,R)$. In this problem the parameters are absolutely real, so jumping to complex space isn't justified.

Comment: It is certainly justified to classify first over $\Bbb C$, and then over $\Bbb R$. And indeed, then it is $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb R)$. A classification of *real* perfect Lie algebras in dimension $6$ has been done as well.

Comment: I disagree. One thing I'm trying to do here is find complex subspaces using the almost complex structure and a matrix $J$ with $J^2=-1$. I've yet to find any reference that does that, everyone just makes real numbers complex, which isn't justified.

Comment: I disagree. The classification you seek is available anyway, complex or real, both of them.

Comment: I know of the dim 6 classifications of these groups, I'll read them again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Again, these are not groups.

Comment: Indeed it's easy to see that the rotation

    [e1+I*e4, e2+I*e5, e3+I*e6, e1-I*e4, e2-I*e5, e3-I*e6]

breaks this into $su(2) \oplus su(2)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152235/discussion-between-bob-mcelrath-and-dietrich-burde).